# Get all rows using entity framework dbset

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbset

I want to select all rows from a table using the following type of syntax:

```cs
public IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies()
{
    return DbContext.Set<Company>()
    .// Select all
}
```

Forgive me as I am completely new to EF.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`Set<T>()` is already `IQueryable<T>` and it returns all rows from table

```
public IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies()
{
    return DbContext.Set<Company>();    
}
```

Also generated `DbContext` will have named properties for each table. Look for `DbContext.Companies` - it's same as `DbContext.Set<Company>`()

Comment: Does this not need async?

Comment: It does not *need* async, but it is compatible with it.

Answer (score 23):

The normal way to do this is by instantiating your dbContext.

For example:

```
public IQueryable<Company> GetCompanies()
{
    using(var context = new MyContext()){ 
        return context.Companies;
    }
}
```

There are lots of good tutorials on using CodeFirst Entity framework (which i assume you are using if you have a DbContext and are new)

- http://codefirst.codeplex.com/
- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

Answer (score 10):

I prefer work on list, also have all relations here

For example:

```
public List<Company> GetCompanies()
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        return context.Companies.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `.ToListAsync()` if you want to do this asynchronously and avoid the blocking call